# red and blue channels swapped between png -> cairo -> x11

Tags: png, x11, endianness, cairo

I am using libcairo2, version 1.13.0~20140204-0ubuntu1 to get some PNG file into an X11 Pixmap. It basically works, but the red and blue channels are swapped. I know this has something to do with either endianness or BGR vs RGB formats. However, I don't find any part in the Cairo or X11 library to do this swap.

My current code is here:

```
cairo_surface_t* cairo_source = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png(filename.c_str());

Pixmap pixmap_dest = XCreatePixmap(display, 
                                   RootWindow(display, screen), 
                                   cairo_image_surface_get_width(cairo_source),
                                   cairo_image_surface_get_height(cairo_source), 
                                   DefaultDepth(display, screen)
                                  );

cairo_surface_t* cairo_dest = cairo_xlib_surface_create(display, 
                                                        pixmap_dest,
                                                        DefaultVisual(display, screen), 
                                                        cairo_image_surface_get_width(cairo_source),
                                                        cairo_image_surface_get_height(cairo_source)
                                                       );

cairo_t* cr = cairo_create(cairo_dest);

cairo_set_source_surface(cr, cairo_source, 0.0, 0.0);

cairo_paint(cr);
```

Any ideas about how to change/fix this?